# Laravel Failed to authenticate on SMTP server

Tags: php, laravel

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xxxxx@xxxx.org" using 2 possible authenticators

I have two Mail (send mail controller) functions on laravel. One works fine with the credentials one throws this error? Not sure what is causing it.

Comment: can you show the error log? Also, make sure that the ports are correct. Some SMTP servers use unusual ports. Also, what do you mean that you have two mail functions?

Comment: @mankowitz laravel send mail controller. One works the other doesnt using same config in .env